# How to achieve this header with html and css?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to design this kind of header (like in the attached image) in my site with no success is any one can help please?

Header I am trying to design

[image]

[Web site with this header](http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1295?originUrl=http://www.wix.com/website/templates?criteria=wedding&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=1)

Comment: in this site you can view it but I can't extract all of it from there : http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1295?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%3Fcriteria%3Dwedding&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=1

Comment: inspect the element (chrome inspector/firebug) on the page and use the same style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create this:

**html**

```
<h1 class="ribbon">
   <strong class="ribbon-content">CAPTURE|WEDDING PHOTOGRAPHY</strong>
</h1>
```

**css**

```
.ribbon {
 font-size: 16px !important;
 /* This ribbon is based on a 16px font side and a 24px vertical rhythm. I've used em's to position each element for scalability. If you want to use a different font size you may have to play with the position of the ribbon elements */
 width: 50%;    
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
color: rgb(134, 152, 158);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 2em; /* Adjust to suit */
 margin: 2em auto 3em; /* Based on 24px vertical rhythm. 48px bottom margin - normally 24 but the ribbon 'graphics' take up 24px themselves so we double it. */
}
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: -1em;
 border: 1.5em solid #fff;
 z-index: -1;
}
.ribbon:before {
 left: -2em;
 border-right-width: 1.5em;
 border-left-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon:after {
 right: -2em;
 border-left-width: 1.5em;
 border-right-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 left: 0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qwKS/)

You can play with colors size etc.

Source for css: [css ribbon](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/)

Answer (score 1):

That is a **Ribbon**.

Knowing that, you can focus your [Google search](https://www.google.it/search?q=ribbon%20css) with amazing results:

- [3D Ribbon Generator](http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/#preview)
- [Ribbon Builder](http://livetools.uiparade.com/ribbon-builder.html#)
- [Ribbon on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/)

Enjoy